# how to get the count of the Records in sql?

Tags: sql-server-2008, count

Hi all i have two tables

```
    Projects
  ----------
  ProjectID|ProjectNAme
    1      |asdasd
    2      |adas
    3      |asdfdf
```

and

```
  Bugs
-------
BugID|Title|ProjectID
  1  |asda |1
  2  |asdfs|1
  3  |sdfsdf|2
  4  |asfsd|2
```

now what i want is,to get the count of no of bugs the project has...and if the project doesnot has any bugs then i should get the count as 0..i had been trying this query...i dnt get the count 0 if projectID doesnot exist in Bug table can any one help me here

```
 Select 
    P.projectName
    , Count(B.BugID) As BugCount  
 from bugs B inner join projects P 
 on P.ProjectId = B.ProjectId
 group by P.projectName
```

Comment: You are better off doing `group by P.ProjectId, P.projectName` unless the name has a unique constraint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Select P.projectName, Count(B.BugID) As BugCount  
 from projects P 
      left join bugs B 
          on P.ProjectId = B.ProjectId 
 group by P.projectName
```